# Facebook Test User unable to access my web page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to test the Facebook login feature for a website staging environment, but when logging in with a test user I see this error message: 
Error
User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration.

I have set App Domain to http://www.mysite-stage.com/. I've also added a Website platform for my app and set the site URL to http://www.mysite-stage.com/.

The website http://www.mysite-stage.com is actually accessible to everybody on the web, so there should be no issues there.

This method of testing Facebook integration for the site was working up to about 1-2 months ago, so I'm a little confused as to why it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you created the test user for that application?

Facebook won't let you login as a test user that was created under a different app than the one you are trying to sign in with. 
Facebook test users are app-specific.

Yo can also create test users through the facebook developers site:
http://developers.facebook.com/apps/ 
- Select your app
- Roles
- Test Users

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't add a comment yet, the problem is with you having made your app available to the public but you are trying to sign in with a test account.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the

```
installed=true
```

parameter once you use

```
POST /{app-id}/accounts/test-users
```

to create the Test Users? See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/accounts/test-users#publish

Comment: Yup, I've tried: https://graph.facebook.com/{app-id}/accounts/test-users?installed=true&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token= {app-id|app-secret}. Still received the same message

Comment: did you found the solution ?
I am getting the same error .. :(